# Source code for Eclipse Cola Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Where can I find the Eclipse Cola plugin's source code? Is there a git or cvs repository?

Preferably one that contains only the plugin and nothing else, but if it's a part of a large repository than that's fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to those repositories are actually dead. I got cola from: https://github.com/eclipse/ecf/tree/8803dcc3dbe11e5125e034323e2eb2ebb87bd168/framework/bundles/org.eclipse.ecf.docshare

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/RT_Shared_Editing#The_Cola_Source

Answer (score 1):

A simple [Google search](http://bit.ly/K6sMIc) revealed that it is in fact [open source](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RT_Shared_Editing#The_Cola_Source).

- Host: ecf1.osuosl.org
- Repository Path: /ecf
- Module: applications/org.eclipse.ecf.example.sharededitor.cola
- User name: anonymous